# Prove that every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of the coordinate ring $\Bbb C[V]$ is the intersection of maximal prime ideals containing it.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of the ring $\Bbb C[x_1, \dots x_n]$ is the intersection of maximal prime ideals containing $\mathfrak{p}$. Prove the same result for the coordinate ring $\Bbb C[V]$, where $V \subset \Bbb A^n$ is an affine variety.

The coordinate ring $\Bbb C[V]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I(V)$ so what I need to show is that if I take a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset \Bbb C[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I(V)$, then $\mathfrak{p} = \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathfrak{m}} \mathfrak{m}$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal prime ideal.

Is this a proof where I need to show both inclusions $\subset$ and $\supset$ or is there some clever way to approach this?

I couldn't get anywhere by taking $f \in \mathfrak{p}$. The only properties I know for prime ideals are that if the product $fg \in \mathfrak{p}$, then either $f \in \mathfrak{p}$ or $g \in \mathfrak{p}$, but I don't think this is something I should consider here.

Comment: Have you learned about the Nullstellensatz yet? If I recall, this is an equivalent formulation. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812391/every-prime-ideal-of-a-finitely-generated-mathbbr-algebra-is-an-intersectio) for how to do it over $\mathbb{R}$, the case of $\mathbb{C}$ should be easier.

Comment: I have! Does the result follow from the fact that the radical of and ideal $J$ is the intersection of all primes containing $J$?

Comment: A ring having this property is called a Jacobson ring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring

Answer (score 2):

I'll give the argument for $\mathbf{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$; see if you can modify it for the $\mathbf{C}[V]$ case.

The $\subset$ inclusion is immediate. Conversely, let $f \in \bigcap_{\mathfrak{m} \supset \mathfrak{p}}\mathfrak{m}$. We have that $f \in \mathfrak{m}$ for all maximal ideals containing $\mathfrak{p}$. What does $f \in \mathfrak{m}$ mean? It implies that $V(f) \supset V(\mathfrak{m})$, i.e. $f$ vanishes at the point $V(\mathfrak{m})$. What does $\mathfrak{m} \supset \mathfrak{p}$ mean? It implies that $V(\mathfrak{m}) \subset V(\mathfrak{p})$, i.e. each $V(\mathfrak{m})$ is a point lying on the affine variety $V(\mathfrak{p})$. Putting the two together, we have that $f$ vanishes at every point on $V(\mathfrak{p})$, and therefore $V(f) \supset V(\mathfrak{p})$, which means that $I(V(f)) \subset I(V(\mathfrak{p}))$, or $\sqrt{(f)}\subset \sqrt{\mathfrak{p}} = \mathfrak{p}$ by the Nullstellensatz. Since $f \in \sqrt{(f)}$, the reverse containment $\supset$ follows.

Comment: Thanks for this! I got a hint that for $\Bbb C[V]$ I should use the correspondence between ideals of $\Bbb C[x_1, \dots x_n]/\mathfrak{p}$ and ideals of $\Bbb C[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ containing $\mathfrak{p}$, but I still am confused about how I should use this correspondence.

Comment: @Jonas: Try using the fact that this correspondence preserves primality/maximality of ideals. The result should then follow from what I've written above.

Comment: So in a sense I can just map $\mathfrak{p} \longmapsto \varphi(\mathfrak{p})$ where $\varphi$ is the bijection giving the correspondence. Now $\varphi(\mathfrak{p})$ is also prime and I need to show the equality $\varphi(\mathfrak{p}) = \bigcap_{\varphi(\mathfrak{m}) \supset \varphi(\mathfrak{p})} \varphi(\mathfrak{m})$? Each of these maximal and prime ideals under $\varphi$ are also maximal and prime so bascially the exact argument you gave should work here? Should I be concerned about the varieties $V(\varphi(\mathfrak{p}))$ and $V(\varphi(\mathfrak{m}))$?

Comment: Be careful. You start with a prime ideal $\overline{\mathfrak{q}} \in \mathbf{C}[V]$ and lift this via the correspondence to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q} \subset \mathbf{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ containing $\mathfrak{p}$. Invoke the argument in my answer, and then pass back to the quotient $\mathbf{C}[V]$.